# Mask numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have an input to coloumns of a dataframe as 12345 and want to output to excel sheet as 1XXX5 how to do this . The data type in the dataframe coloumn is an integer

```
df=pd.read_excel('INVAMF.xls',sheetname=4,header=0,skiprows=0)
#df created 

print df.dtypes
print np.count_nonzero(pd.value_counts(df['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'].values))

s = (df['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'])

print s
s = s.astype(str)

s.apply(lambda x: x[0] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])

print s

0        32642
1        32643
2        32644
3        32677
4        32680
5        32680
6        32688
7        32688
8        32695
9        32708
10       32708
11       32709
12       32710
13       32734
14       32734
15       32738
16       32738
17        6109
18        6109
```

1. `List item`

Comment: Can you post raw data, your code and desired output as your question is a little unclear

Comment: i cannot as it is sensitive to the work i am doing ..but  will elaborate . THink of it as numeric integers for your phone number i need to hide the data in the data sheet for reporting purposes. So my output should have middle integers hidden by X and i want to save it in a axcel file

Comment: like if my number is 8815392 i should get 8XXXXX2 in the output

Comment: Why can't you post randomized data no one is asking you to post sensitive data

Comment: You need to assign the result of the operation: `s = s.apply(lambda x: x[0] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've failed to post any data and code here is a general form assuming that numbers are varying length:

```
In [141]:
s = pd.Series([8815392,2983])
s = s.astype(str)
s.apply(lambda x: x[0] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])

Out[141]:
0    8XXXXX2
1       2XX3
dtype: object
```

if the numbers are equal length you can use a vectorised method to set the entire column:

```
In [142]:
s = pd.Series([8815392,1291283])
s = s.astype(str)
s.str[0] + 'X' * (s.str.len() - 2)[0] + s.str[-1]

Out[142]:
0    8XXXXX2
1    1XXXXX3
dtype: object
```

Also just to clarify a common problem you need to assign back the operation as most pandas methods return a copy and don't work in place, although some methods do have a `inplace` arg. So you need to do the following:

```
s = s.apply(lambda x: x[0] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])
```

Comment: please don't post data in comments, edit your question and ensure the data is formatted

Comment: they are of unequal length and vectorised one cannot be used for the full coloumn. the coloumn is a part of a dataframe and when i use the first method the output is not coming as expected .

Comment: I can't answer hypothetical questions without raw data and code that shows this error, edit your question as you waste my time telling me the symptoms without posting code in your question

Comment: I have updated the code and the result from the data ..the result and input are the same. The data type is int64